# GRUB see LVM disk with Kubuntu only after enter to BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, lvm

I have a boot problem.

I've installed *Kubuntu 13.10* from a standard image file (using the standard installer) without manual partitioning. During the set-up process I chose the option "Setup on entire encrypted LVM". I have two disks: `hd0` (with a pre-installed Windows 8) and a new one `hd1` with Kubuntu. After the installation completed, I  rebooted and got the following message:

```
       [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For
         the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command
         completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
         completions of a device/filename. ]
grub>
```

I typed "reboot", then entered the BIOS, exiting without saving changes and I can now see a normal grub with listed options Kubuntu, Windows and so on.

I can successfully boot Kubuntu from it.

If I type `ls` in the minimal grub, it shows 6 partitions of `hd0` and none on `hd1`. It seems GRUB started to see `hd1` only after the BIOS preloads it somehow.

I also tried to modify grub.cfg adding `instmod lvm` but was unsuccessful, probably because GRUB resides on the LVM itself. I read several forum threads but even don't know how to classify this problem.

Could anyone help me?

**Update**. My configuration can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9544213/)...

**Update** If I type `exit` in the minimal GRUB I get the normal GRUB.

**Update** Here is 'sudo parted --list' output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9547727/)

Comment: For the future: you can use "`" (backticks) instead of <code> (less to type)

Comment: Could you delete all your comments below the one that says "1"?
Furthermore, do a `sudo parted --list` and post the output to a new http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Odd.. the fact that entering the bios or exiting from the minimal grub makes it work points to the disk simply needing extra time to work properly, but ls still not recognizing partitions on the drive after waiting a few seconds says otherwise.  Either way, this is a problem with your hardware; possibly the disk, but most likely your bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [`sudo parted --list` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9547727/), you've put your boot partition onto the LVM...  Bad idea!  Head to [The Linux Documentation project](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/benefitsoflvmsmall.html) to read why you shouldn't...

*`boot` is not included on the LV because bootloaders don't understand LVM volumes yet. It's possible boot on LVM will work, but you run the risk of having an unbootable system.* [sic]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really not the answer I'm looking for. Anyway I'm appreciated for you help. Can we make conclusion, that the option "Setup on entire encrypted LVM" in the Kubuntu installer works incorrectly? Can I move /boot to a separate partition on the working system or it will be simpler to full reinstall the system? What size of /boot will be sufficient without neccesity of regularly cleaning of kernel updates?

Comment: 5 years of not cleaning?  10 GB.
better to re-install, create swap and /boot on a real partition, and the rest on LVM!  ;-)